# How to conditionally skip a test in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, nose, nose2

I would like to skip some test functions when a condition is met, for example:

```
@skip_unless(condition)
def test_method(self):
    ...
```

Here I expect the test method to be reported as skipped if `condition` evaluated to true. I was able to do this with some effort with nose, but I would like to see if it is possible in nose2.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24639671/108197) describes a method for skipping all tests in [nose2](https://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 16):

### Generic Solution:

You can use `unittest` skip conditions which will work with nosetests, nose2 and pytest. There are two options:

```
class TestTheTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.skipIf(condition, reason)
    def test_that_runs_when_condition_false(self):
        assert 1 == 1

    @unittest.skipUnless(condition, reason)
    def test_that_runs_when_condition_true(self):
        assert 1 == 1
```

### Pytest

Using `pytest` framework:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(condition, reason)
def test_that_runs_when_condition_false():
    assert 1 == 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The built in [unittest.skipUnless()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures) method and it should work with nose:

Answer (score 1):

Using nose:

```
#1.py
from nose import SkipTest

class worker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.skip_condition = False

class TestBench:
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.core = worker()
    def setup(self):
        print "setup", self.core.skip_condition
    def test_1(self):
        self.core.skip_condition = True
        assert True
    def test_2(self):
        if self.core.skip_condition:
            raise SkipTest("Skipping this test")
```

> nosetests -v --nocapture 1.py

```
1.TestBench.test_1 ... setup False
ok
1.TestBench.test_2 ... setup True
SKIP: Skipping this test

----------------------------------------------------------------------
XML: /home/aladin/audio_subsystem_tests/nosetests.xml
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK (SKIP=1)
```